# Input/output error while using google colab to read Google dirve files

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am training my model with colab.
I have encountered this error more than once, when I use the enumeration function in colab to iterate my training data on Google Drive.
The time when the error occurred is uncertain. The error may be after training a few epoch, or it may happen in several iterations.

I tried to modify the path of the dataset in Google Drive, or reduce the batchsize, these have no effect.

```
   192     batch_time = AverageMeter()
   193     losses = AverageMeter()
--> 194     for i, sample in enumerate(train_loader):
   195         start = time.time()
   196         input = sample['image'].cuda()
```

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2530, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: './nyud_cropped/train_labels/001187.png'
```

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to first copy data out of Drive to the ephemeral VM machine before training. That may also speed things up.

Comment: Moving data to the ephemeral VM machine successfully solved my problem，thank you so much for your suggestion：）

Answer (score 0):

the same error appeared to me when I executed the copy command that it can't access the folder that contains the data set due to I_O error and google drive had time out

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34463521)